# Contact names don’t appear on lock screen whatsapp notifications

Tags: display, contacts, notifications, whatsapp.app

the problem I’m experiencing is that contact names do not appear on whatsapp lock screen notifications. For example, if I get a message from Dad, whatsapp only displays the whatsapp logo and “message”, without displaying the sender. When I turn on message previews, I can see both the contact name and the message preview, but I used to be able to see just the contact name (“Dad has sent you a message”) instead of having to see the preview. This just happened as I updated to ios 11.3.1. Anyone having a similar problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: I have the same problem dude.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [Basic Customer Support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y) question. Please see the meta post link for details on how to proceed if you can edit the post and, if put on Hold, have the Hold reviewed.  You can also contact the software developer for assistance with their product.

Comment: Obviously I haven’t been able to solve the problem even after doing what every other answer said on other posts, or I wouldn’t be asking this question.

Comment: Having the same problem. This question is relevant. If it’s off topic or not, the purpose is to have an answer.